# PHP uSort Optimization?

Tags: php, usort

Just wondering if anyone can optimize this usortMonths() function to be better? Basically I have an array of months unsorted, $bob, and I want them sorted by month, not alphabetically.

The code works fine, but its my first time with uSort and I wouldnt mind if anyone can give any suggestions of improvement?

```
function usortMonths($a, $b) {
$months = array('JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER');
    $key = array(0 => 0,1 => 0,2 => FALSE, 3 => FALSE);
    if(array_search(strtoupper($a),$months)!==FALSE) {
        $key[0] = array_search(strtoupper($a),$months);
        $key[2] = TRUE; }
    if(array_search(strtoupper($b),$months)!==FALSE) {
        $key[1] = array_search(strtoupper($b),$months);
        $key[3] = TRUE; }
    if($key[2] && $key[3]){
        if($key[0] < $key[1]) {return -1;}
        if($key[0] == $key[1]){return 0;}
        if($key[0] > $key[1]) {return 1;}
    }
}

$bob = array('april','august','december','february','January','july','june','march','may','november','october','september',);       
usort($bob,"usortMonths");
var_dump($bob);
```

Comment: Instead of `<code>`-tags, use an indent of 4 spaces to make text show up as code. If you need to indent a large block, you can just select that text and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: @Wrikken thanks - I'll remember that in future! :)

Comment: I would replace the months by their month number, and then compare those. Now you are converting the month to a numerical version by array reference, for every comparison you do. What is the array size you want to handle? 

Btw: this is more a question for code review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) then for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Arend, yeah but then surely that involves changing the input array, which I cannae do.  And I didnt even know about code review - sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
function usortMonths($a, $b) {
    $months = array('JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER');
    return array_search(strtoupper($a), $months) - array_search(strtoupper($b), $months);
}
```

Comment: Well, thats a nice efficient way of doing it. Brilliant. Thank you very much.